# c program run on codeblocks but not on clion how is it even possible?

Tags: c, codeblocks, clion

i successfully run it on codeblocks, but my clion doesnt display anything when i run it.
i usually use clion, so im very furious about this. (dont want to be obligated to use codeblocks)
please help a poor lost soul.
this is the code.

dont have a lot more to say, but still stackoverflow wants me to write more, so here i am.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int **malloc2dR(int r,int c);
int **MATinit(int r, int c);
void MATstampa(int **m, int r, int c);
void change(int **M, int r, int c);

int main() {
    int r=3,c=4;
    int **M=MATinit(r,c);

    MATstampa(M,r,c);
    change(M,r,c);
    MATstampa(M,r,c);

    return 0;
}

int **malloc2dR(int r, int c){
    int **m;
    int i;

    m=malloc(r*sizeof (int *));
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        m[i]=malloc(c*sizeof (int));

    return m;
}

int **MATinit(int r, int c){
    int **M=malloc2dR(r,c);
    int i,j;

    printf("scrivere in input i valori della matrice %dx%d\n",r,c);

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            scanf("%d",&M[i][j]);

    return M;
}

void MATstampa(int **m, int r, int c){
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<r;i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}


void change(int **M, int r, int c) {
    int i, j;
    int ii, jj;
    int **Mfake=malloc2dR(r,c);

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            Mfake[i][j]=M[i][j];

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            if (M[i][j] % 2 == 1) {

                for (ii = 0; ii < r; ii++)
                    Mfake[ii][j] = 1;
                for (jj = 0; jj < c; jj++)
                    Mfake[i][jj] = 1;

            }

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            M[i][j]=Mfake[i][j];

}
```

Comment: Did you try to run a simpler code on clion? It must not be your problem, but note that you forgot to freed  the `MFake` matrix in `change(.)`

Comment: printf("hello world") runs well, this is very mysterious (ps: thanks for the lost free() ) @Damien

Comment: The `#include <stdio.h>` is missing in the shown code. Maybe simply a copy and paste issue. Your code seems to work well on my PC (cygwin)

Comment: added it, lost it in the copy-paste process @Damien